# PHP: How to fix curl_exec() error 60: unable to get local issuer certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, php-curl

(This question was originally titled, "Why is curl_exec() failing in this script?" But by adding calls to `curl_errno()` and `curl_error()` in the script, I found out that the problem was the certificate, and I've edited the question accordingly.)

The following script:

```
<?php
$sDataFile = '<path>\journal-issue-ToC.htm';
$sURL = 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14678624/2014/85/1';
$bHeader = false;

$cURLhandle = curl_init();
$FilePointer = fopen($sDataFile, 'wb');

curl_setopt($cURLhandle, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL);
curl_setopt($cURLhandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $FilePointer);
curl_setopt($cURLhandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, $bHeader);

$bResult = curl_exec($cURLhandle);
echo('<br>' . ($bResult === false ? 'Failed to execute' : 'Executed') . ' cURL.');
if(! $bResult) echo('<br>Error #' . curl_errno($cURLhandle) . ': ' . curl_error($cURLhandle));
curl_close($cURLhandle);

fclose($FilePointer);
```

saves the empty file "journal-issue-ToC.htm" and generates the following browser output:

```
Failed to execute cURL.
Error #60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

So it appears that cURL encounters a certificate problem that doesn't happen when I access the [requested URL](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14678624/2014/85/1) in the browser. What do I need to know about certificates in order to get this script to work?

I'm running PHP 7.2.2 on IIS 7.5 under Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to know about certificates in order to get cURL to work is in an [article on GitHub](https://github.com/yabacon/paystack-php/wiki/cURL-error-60:-SSL-certificate-problem:-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-(see-http:--curl.haxx.se-libcurl-c-libcurl-errors.html)), which explains the need for certificates in cURL and how to get and apply them:

- What we're talking about are SSL certificates, needed for the https protocol. "CA" stands for "certificate authorities".
- Download the certificates from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem ([documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)).
- In the file "php.ini", in the section on cURL, uncomment the command for the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option and specify the location of the downloaded file "cacert.pem”. After saving the ini file, restart the webserver to effect the change.

I did this with a couple of variations:

- I chose to set the value of `CURLOPT_CAINFO` in the function `curl_setopt()` instead of in the file "php.ini".
- I at first got error 77, "error setting certificate verify locations". This was fixed by moving the file "cacert.pem" to a folder under the folder "Program Files\PHP".

After doing that, the script ran without error and the output file was not empty. But what it contained was still not what I need, which is the subject of a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584173/php-do-i-need-to-use-cookies-in-this-curl-script).